# Compiler error message - File not found

Tags: c#, xna, compiler-warnings

I tried to fix that, but i don't have idea what can be wrong. Can someone give me some advice?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try load @"graphics\teddybear0.png"

Comment: *"\graphics\teddybear0" - File not found* ...what piece of *File not found* do you not understand? The error is kinda straight forward, isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

@".\graphics\teddybear0.png"

Point at start of the path means "current directory".

Also, for the future, double point at start of path "..\" means "one level up of current directory", "parent of current directory".

Current means your base working directory of application (technically where your .exe file is)

Comment: ".\" not just "."

Comment: @".\graphics\teddybear0.png"

Comment: My bad... I just mistook something else. Thanks for your time.